# Is the improvement from switching on http/2.0 in Cloudfront for an SPA noticeable for the average user of a large site during bootstrap?

Tags: performance, http2

We have a large SPA in backbone and Angular that calls out to a set of Java APIs for a financial system with a large number of users.

One person said:

> Switching on [http/2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) will have a massive different for our users in terms of page load time due to the nature of the protocol.

Another person said:

> Browsers like Chrome are actually pretty good even without [http/2.0](https://http2.github.io/faq/). Switching it on won't make a noticeable different to the end user.

We made the change, and measured static page load times before and after the change. We didn't see a difference over 48 hours of data each before and after the change. (By both browser tests, and getting logging data on page load times forwarded to the application from the browser in our logs.)

My question is: **Is the improvement from switching on http/2.0 in [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-http2/) for an SPA noticeable for the average user of a large site during bootstrap?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too vague a question to answer I’m afraid.

Some of the things to consider:

- Is your site super optimised with HTTP/1 performance issue workarounds (e.g. 
  concatenation, spriting, sharding) that HTTP/2 (which looks to remove the need for those) provides no real noticeable performance benefits?
- Is your site so full of crappy JavaScript that HTTP downloads (which HTTP/2 looks to make more efficient) are a tiny and almost unnoticeable part of the performance problem in the grand scale of things?
- Is your site bandwidth bound (e.g. full of print quality images) so that bandwidth rather than HTTP queuing is the problem?
- Is your backend and/or web server so sucky that it takes a long time to generate your pages so again the HTTP transfer part is a tiny, almost unnoticeable part of the problem?
- Is your site a really small site with just one HTML page and one JavaScript load?
- Could your site be more optimised for HTTP/2 (e.g. hosting everything on a single domain, potentially using HTTP/2 Push...etc.) to allow you to get more performance than you could out of HTTP/2?

All of these things could impact whether switching to HTTP/2 makes a noticeable difference or not. [Google found that a sample of sites get a 27%-60% performance improvement for SPDY](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper) (that HTTP/2 is based upon), but it really does depend on the site in question.

Ultimately HTTP/2 aims to make downloading many assets more efficient as this is inefficient under HTTP/1 - and particularly on low latency conditions. If you don’t have many assets, or downloading those is not a problem then HTTP/2 then you may not notice much difference.

I’ve a [blog post to help show the problems in HTTP/1 that HTTP/2 looks to address](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/why-do-we-need-http2/) (including analysing a real world example - Amazon.com) which may help you look at your site for the same potential issues (full disclosure it’s part of [a book I’m writing on the subject](https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action?a_aid=tunetheweb&a_bid=a810f9b6)).

Comment: I also want to mention that cloudfront does not support proper resource prioritisation over http/2. Take a look here https://github.com/andydavies/http2-prioritization-issues. Which means that resources with higher priority get stuck behind other streams with lower...